# How to unzip tar.z using C#

Tags: c#, gzip, zip

I tried DotNetZip、SharpZipLib even use cmd to command rar.exe

but it's does'nt work

and the code is I reference ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip、ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar to do

```
 FileInfo tarFileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\*.tar.Z");
        using (Stream sourceStream = new GZipInputStream(tarFileInfo.OpenRead()))
        {
            using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(sourceStream, TarBuffer.DefaultBlockFactor))
            {
                tarArchive.ExtractContents(targetDirectory.FullName);
            }
        }
```

I'll get error message like this：

> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipException: 'Error GZIP header, 
>   second magic byte doesn't match

so how to fix it and success to unzip?

Comment: `.z` is the format used by [compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress), which uses [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), a completely different compression algorithm than those used by ZIP or GZIP. You can't use `GZipInputStream to read a `.Z` file.

Comment: ok! now I knew *.Z different with *.zip、*.tar etc. howevery have any solution to unzip *.Z using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.z` uses LZW, a completely different algorithm than those used in `.zip` or `.gz` files. SharpZipLib supports LZW through the `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Lzw` namespace. The namespaces used for each algorithm are shown in the repo's landing page, in the [Namespace Layout](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib#namespace-layout) section.

You can check [the LZW unit test file](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/test/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tests/Lzw/LzwTests.cs) although the code is essentially the same as that used for other formats, eg:

```
using (var inStream = new LzwInputStream(File.OpenRead(@"D:\*.tar.Z")))
{
    using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(inStream, TarBuffer.DefaultBlockFactor))
    {
        tarArchive.ExtractContents(targetDirectory.FullName);
    }
}
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress) it's possible that the compressed file uses DEFLATE instead of LZW. In this case you'd have to use `InflaterInputStream` instead of `LzwInputStream`.

The [TAR sample](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/samples/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Samples/cs/Cmd_Tar/Cmd_Tar.cs) in SharpZipLib's repo uses InflaterInputStream, GZipInputStream or BZip2InputStream based on a switch